# REGEX for multiple lines - powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a little problem with regex in powershell. My REGEX works only for one line. I need to work on multiple lines.

For example html:

```
<li> test </li>
</ul>
```

I want REGEX took everything, including "/ul>". My suggestion is:

```
'(^.*<li>.*</ul>)'
```

But it donesn't work. Is it even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911293/multiline-regex-in-powershell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It **depends** on what regex method you are using.

If you use the .NET `Regex::Match`, there is a third parameter where you can define additional `regex`options. Use `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline` here:

```
$html = 
@'
<li> test </li>
</ul>
'@

$regex = '(^.*<li>.*\</ul>)' 

[regex]::Match($html,$regex,[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline).Groups[0].Value
```

If you want to use the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet, you have to specifiy the singleline option `(?s)` within your `regex`:

```
$html = 
@'
<li> test </li>
</ul>
'@

$regex = '(?s)(^.*<li>.*\</ul>)' 

$html | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | Select -Expand Matches | select -expand Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a multi-line single-line regex, with `-match`:

```
$string = @'
notmached
<li> test </li>
</ul>
notmatched
'@


$regex = @'
(?ms)(<li>.*</li>.*?
\s*</ul>)
'@

$string -match $regex > $null
$matches[1]

<li> test </li>
</ul>
```