# Select a block of text from a file using powershell

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, notepad++

Disclaimer:

- I know to read in text files with the `-raw` switch
- I know about the `(?sm)` and `-AllMatches` qualifiers
- I've read the other similar solutions ([Multiline regex to match config block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block) and [REGEX for multiple lines - powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913593/regex-for-multiple-lines-powershell)) but can't successfully modify their solutions for my use case

I have a log file ~1200 lines long, so not overly huge. The log file is a mixture of 'plain text' and then that 'plain text' is repeated as XML. I want to select (and ultimately remove) the blocks of 'plain text' so the blocks of XML remain.

The plain text blocks start with `Log Name:` then some more text on that line, then multiple lines with text, finishing with `Event Xml:` (nothing else on this line).

Example plain text block:

```
Log Name:      AD FS Tracing/Debug
(multiple lines of text)
Event Xml:
```

My attempts either select nothing, or everything, or eveything from the first `Log Name:` to the last `Event Xml:`

Example regex pattern:

```
'(?smi)Log Name:.*Event Xml:'
```

Have tried this in powershell and notepad++. The log files are from Event Viewer on Windows 2012R2, so alternative solution to solve my overall issue: How to you export just the `XML` from Event Viewer?

**Edit:** (@ https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)

`'(?si)Log Name:.*?Event Xml:'` selects the entire log file. I had tried modifying the similar questions, but it doesn't select what I want. Hence why I asked my specific question - it's not a duplicate.

Comment: `'(?si)Log Name:.*?Event Xml:'`

Comment: Because this been marked as duplicate can't answer it, but here's the solution. Checked the regex on regex101.com and `(?sig)Log Name:.*?Event Xml:` worked. So the regex was correct, powershell wasn't. In the end changed from Select-String to the [regex]::matches class/method `[regex]::Matches($raw,'(?msi)Log Name:.*?Event Xml:') | %{$_.value}`

Comment: It is still an off-topic question and a dupe of the post mentioned (because your attempt was with a *greedy* quantifier). If you want it reopened, edit the question to inlcude all the relevant code that did not work.