# PowerShell Regular Expression Multiline

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, multiline

I want to match following multiline in a text file.

[1750256247]
;Rev: B,5

I tried following, however could not succeed. Could you please help me?

```
$fileContent | Select-String "(?smi)(^[1750256247](-|\s*$))(^;Rev: B,5$)" -AllMatches | Foreach {$.Matches} | Foreach {$.Value}
```

Comment: You can also use `$fileContent | Select-String "(?i)\[1750256247][-\s]*;Rev: B,5" -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value}`

Comment: npinti's does not work on my end either. Did you try `$fileContent | Select-String "(?i)\[1750256247][-\s]*;Rev: B,5" -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value}`? BTW, do you mean a `\r\n` linebreak or a `<br>`?

Comment: Hi stribizhev, Yes I tried yours also. The same happened. I can not understand why. I mean [CR][LF]

Comment: Maybe beacuse the question is unclear?

Comment: String is as follows : 
[1750256247][CR][LF];Rev: B,5[CR][LF]

Comment: I found a solution. Please check this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911293/multiline-regex-in-powershell

Comment: Cool, then please remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly 100% sure what you are after, but changing your expression to this: `(?smi)(^\[1750256247\](.|-|\s*$))(^;Rev: B,5$)` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/yB5aE7/1)) works.

Some issues with your expression:

1. In regex syntax, the `[` and `]` characters denote character sets, that is, a set of characters of which the engine will attempt to match one of. If you need to match the actual `[` and `]` characters, you will need to escape them through the use of the `\` character.
2. You are using the `s` modifier, thus allowing the period character to also match newlines, but you are not using the period character.

EDIT: As per @stribizhev's suggestion, you can use `(?smi)(^\[1750256247](.|-|\s*$))(^;Rev: B,5$)`. Personally I would go for the first option because I consider it more readable, but opinions will most likely differ on this.

Comment: Only `[` should be escaped here. `[` must be escaped outside of character class, and `]` should be escaped inside a character class if not in the initial position.

Comment: @stribizhev: So `\[foo]` will match `[foo]`?

Comment: Yes, the `]` is disambiguated as a literal symbol in most regex flavors. In Powershell, .NET regex is used, so, it will work like this.

Comment: Hi npinti,Thank you for the quick reply. There is a line break after "[1750256247]". Then comes ";Rev: B,5" at the beginning of nest line. I tried what you wrote but did not work.

Comment: @stribizhev: I see what you mean. Don't you think it hinders readability?

Comment: @npinti: I think the opposite

Comment: @stribizhev: I see. I've added your response as well for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I find multiline regex easier to write and more intuitive to read if you build the regex in a here-string, with the newlines embedded.

```
$regex = @'
(?ms)\[1750256247\]\s*
;Rev: B,5\s*
'@
```

Just paste the literal string you're trying to match into the regex and then escape and add metacharacters for things like trailing whitespace as needed.